# Ayuda con Controller Generic en c#

Tags: c#, jquery, json

les cuento tengo un controller de nombre GenericController, en el intento poner todos los métodos que voy a usar mas de una vez, el código de dicho controller es el siguiente.

```
namespace WebDBT.Controllers
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using WebDBT.Models;


    public class GenericController : Controller
    {

        private static WebDBTContext db = new WebDBTContext();


        public static List<MtoRequerimiento> GetPartidas(int? Id)
        {

            List<MtoRequerimiento> List = new List<MtoRequerimiento>();
            var list = db.MtoRequerimientos.Where(item => item.MtoRequerimientoId == Id);
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                List.Add(new MtoRequerimiento
                {
                    MtoRequerimientoId = item.MtoRequerimientoId,
                    Descripcion = item.Descripcion.Length < 90 ? item.Descripcion : item.Descripcion.Substring(1, 90),
                });
            }       


            return List.OrderBy(p => p.Partida)
                       .ThenBy(p=>p.Gpo).ToList();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }

    }


}
```

ahora este método lo trato de llamar desde json con el siguiente código ,

```
function GetPartidas(id) {

    if (id > 0) {
        $("#MtoRequerimientoId").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#MtoRequerimientoId").empty();
        $("#MtoRequerimientoId").append('<option value="0">Cargando....             </option>');
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: _urlBase + "Generic/GetPartidas",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#MtoRequerimientoId").empty();
                console.log(data);
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                        $("#MtoRequerimientoId").append('<option value="'
                            + data.Value + '">'
                            + data.Text + '</option>');                        
                    });
                    $("#MtoRequerimientoId").attr('disabled', false);
                }
                else {

                    $("#MtoRequerimientoId").html('no existe requerimiento para el procedimiento seleccionado');
                    $("#MtoRequerimientoId").attr('disabled', true);
                }                
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Error al Cargar Partidas.' + ex);
                $("#MtoRequerimientoId").attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $("#MtoRequerimientoId").empty();
        $("#MtoRequerimientoId").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#MtoRequerimientoId").append('<option value="0">[Selecciona Partida]</option>');
    }
}
```

> No se encuentra el recurso. Descripción: HTTP 404. El recurso que está
>   buscando (o una de sus dependencias) se puede haber quitado, haber
>   cambiado de nombre o no estar disponible temporalmente. Revise la
>   dirección URL siguiente y asegúrese de que está escrita correctamente.
>
> Dirección URL solicitada: /Generic/GetPartidas

es posible me puedan ayudar de como debo llamar a ese controller desde json?

gracias

Comment: Qué valor tiene `_urlBase`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los métodos de acción de cualquier controlador, necesitan regresar un `ActionResult`. En este caso con cambiar el tipo de retorno del método deberá y regresar un `View` o `Json` de ser suficiente:

```
public ActionResult GetPartidas(int? Id)
{
    ...
    return View(List.OrderBy(p => p.Partida)
                   .ThenBy(p=>p.Gpo).ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asi te deberia de funcionar.
Debes de generar un JsonResult, como dice su nombre, debes de regresar un Json, en este caso tu listado.
Como es un HttpGET en MVC 3+ hay que especificar JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

```
 public JsonResult GetPartidas(int? Id)
 {

   //Tu Logica

    return Json(new { list=List.OrderBy(p => p.Partida).ThenBy(p=>p.Gpo).ToList()},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );

 }
```

Comment: ok voy a probar

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @Horacio? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde y te dará 2 puntos de reputación). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!